# why is mybatis marking The error may involve defaultParameterMap?

Tags: java, mybatis

Hi I got a method that is supposed to the return a list but instead I´m getting
Error querying database.  Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'CATSTATUSPRINT'.
, The error may exist in com/mapper/CatStatusPrintMapper.xml
, The error may involve defaultParameterMap
, The error occurred while setting parameters

This is my mapper CatStatusPrintMapper.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE mapper
  PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="statusMapper">

     <select id="consultCatStatus" resultMap="catStatusMap">
        SELECT 
            C.ID_STATUS,
            C.NAME_STATUS, 
            C.DESC_STATUS,
            C.ACTIVE
        FROM CATSTATUSPRINT C
         WHERE C.ACTIVE = 1
        ORDER BY C.NAME_STATUS ASC
    </select>

     <select id="consultCatStatus2" resultMap="catStatusMap">
        SELECT 
            C.ID_STATUS,
            C.NAME_STATUS, 
            C.DESC_STATUS,
            C.ACTIVE
        FROM CATSTATUSPRINT C
         WHERE C.ACTIVE = 2
        ORDER BY C.NAME_STATUS ASC
    </select>    

    <resultMap id="catStatusMap" type="catStatus">
        <result column="ID_STATUS" property="idStatus"></result>
        <result column="NAME_STATUS" property="nameStatus"></result>
        <result column="DESC_STATUS" property="descStatus"></result>
        <result column="ACTIVE" property="active"></result>
    </resultMap>

</mapper>
```

Here is my entity bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CatStatusPrint")
public class CatStatusPrintBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID_STATUS")
    private Integer idStatus;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NAME_STATUS")
    private String nameStatus;
    @Column(name = "DESC_STATUS")
    private String descStatus;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private Integer active;

    public CatStatusPrintBean() {
    }

    public CatStatusPrintBean(Integer idStatus) {
        this.idStatus = idStatus;
    }

    public CatStatusPrintBean(Integer idStatus, String nameStatus, Integer active) {
        this.idStatus = idStatus;
        this.nameStatus = nameStatus;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Integer getIdStatus() {
        return idStatus;
    }

    public void setIdStatus(Integer idStatus) {
        this.idStatus = idStatus;
    }

    public String getNameStatus() {
        return nameStatus;
    }

    public void setNameStatus(String nameStatus) {
        this.nameStatus = nameStatus;
    }

    public String getDescStatus() {
        return descStatus;
    }

    public void setDescStatus(String descStatus) {
        this.descStatus = descStatus;
    }

    public Integer getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Integer active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idStatus != null ? idStatus.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And here is my method inside my dao:

```
public List<CatStatusPrintBean> getCatStatusPrint2(){
    session2 = sqlSessionFactory2.openSession();
    try {
        List<CatStatusPrintBean> lstStatus = session2.selectList(TagsPrintConstants.MAPPER_CONSULT_STATUS);            
         return lstStatus;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(TagsPrintConstants.ERROR_OBTENER_CAT_IMPRESION + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        session2.close();
    }
}
```

Why am I getting and error???????
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL query directly to your DB?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that my configuration was pointing to different database.
Once I point it to the correct database it works.